# make syntax automatically from pandas table column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe

```
NAME      DDGNWW
ABC          123
DEF          456
GHI          789
JKL          012
MNO          110
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['ABC', 123], 
    ['DEF', 456], 
    ['GHI', 789], 
    ['JKL', 12], 
    ['MNO', 110]
], 
    columns=['NAME', 'DDGNWW'])
```

Now I want to make SQL syntax based on DDGNWW automatically like:

```
(
    "DDGNWW" = 123 
    OR "DDGNWW" = 456 
    OR "DDGNWW" = 789 
    OR "DDGNWW" = 12 
    OR "DDGNWW" = 110
)
```

Comment: Instead of multiple `OR` statements, why not use `IN`: `'"DDGNWW" IN {}'.format(tuple(df['DDGNWW']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
' OR '.join(df['DDGNWW'].apply(lambda x: '"DDGNWW"={}'.format(x)))
```

Orther way to do with or:

```
'"DDGNWW" IN ' + str(tuple(df['DDGNWW']))
```

Comment: this syntax gives output as 
"ABC" = 123 OR "DEF" = 456 OR "GHI" = 789 OR "JKL" = 012 OR "MNO" = 110
I donot want Name .. I want only "DDGNWW"

Comment: Updated to your output